# Pandas exclude row from dataframe if the value is absent in the other dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to find the rows from pandas `Dataframe_1` if the value in the fourth column within this row exists in any row of the entire first column of `Dataframe_2`. I need to copy these rows to the new table.

**EDIT**

Here I also include the dataframes:

Dataframe_1:

```
           1       2               3  4
 0
 chr1  128611  128681  cuffs_1_128645  .
 chr1  186868  186933  cuffs_2_186901  .
 chr1  186978  187035  cuffs_3_187015  .
 chr1  187054  187122  cuffs_4_187082  .
 chr1  262712  262773  cuffs_5_262742  .
```

Dataframe_2:

```
                            1      2     3      4     5      6     7  8
 0
 cuffs_100001_101338862   1.24   3.11  1.86  11.19  5.59   8.08  0.62  0
 cuffs_100004_101354225   2.49   0.62  1.86   1.86  2.49   1.24  0.00  0
 cuffs_100045_101386584  14.92  14.92  3.11  10.57  5.59  15.54  0.62  0
 cuffs_100089_101719129   2.49   0.62  1.86   5.59  1.86   1.86  0.00  0
 cuffs_100111_101726996   6.84   0.00  3.73   3.11  6.84   2.49  0.62  0
```

Both dataframes are imported from .csv and are huge, so here I've put only a few rows and columns.

This is what I tried:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(Dataframe_1, sep = '\t', index_col=list(range(0,1,2)), header = None)
 df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(Dataframe_2, sep = '\t', index_col=list(range(0,1,2)), header = None)
 df1 = df1[df1[3] == df2[0]]
 df1.to_csv(fileout, sep = '\t', header = False)
```

When performing this I get eight (or so) lines of response referring to the pandas package files, `index.pyx` and `hashtable.pyx` which I don't understand.

Comment: Without an example set of data from the dataframes, it makes it hard to help you. However, I think you may want to try: df1 = df1[df1[3].isin(df2[0])]. If that's not what you're looking for, post a copy and pastable example.

Comment: Thanks, I tested that but it still gave same bunch of response lines and a `KeyError: 0` , presumably KeyError code changes when I change `df2[0]` to `df2[2]` for example. I becomes `KeyError: 2` respectively.

Comment: This is because of the ambiguity of the index operator. Be specific, like for example `df.loc[:, 0]` to get the first column.

Comment: Also, "column" `0` is the index of your dataframe, so you need to something like `df2.index` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
Apparently, none of the tested commands for filtering, be it `df1 = df1[df1[3].isin(df2[0])]` or `df1 = df1[df1[3] == df2[0]]` recognise the "0" columns, which represented the rows indexes. The way out would be to import the Dataframe_2 assigning the columns not like (0,1,2) but (1,2,3) this will lead to the following formatting of the df2:

```
                          0      2     3      4     5      6     7    8    
 1
 1.24   cuffs_100001_101338862   3.11  1.86  11.19  5.59   8.08  0.62    0
 2.49   cuffs_100004_101354225   0.62  1.86   1.86  2.49   1.24  0.00    0
 14.92  cuffs_100045_101386584  14.92  3.11  10.57  5.59  15.54  0.62    0
 2.49   cuffs_100089_101719129   0.62  1.86   5.59  1.86   1.86  0.00    0
 6.84   cuffs_100111_101726996   0.00  3.73   3.11  6.84   2.49  0.62    0
```

Where the "0" column is no longer the index for rows. Then we can apply `df1 = df1[df1[3].isin(df2[0])]`. NOTE: application of `df1 = df1[df1[3] == df2[0]]` will raise the error message `Series lengths must match to compare`

Thanks!